# Is it possible to insert an "independent" slide in a frame, and going back?

Tags: beamer, overlays, slideshow

is there a possibility, while displaying an itemize, to go to an independent frame (or something like that) to show an example for example, and then go back to the itemize ?

something like... that :

```
\begin{frame}[first]
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<1> foo
  \item<2> bar
  % go to [second] and then go back here to see 3rd point
  \item<3> baz
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[second]
 % Some examples
\end{frame}
```

(I don't care if the example second frame is not a real "frame", I'd just want to know the best way to this kind of stuff)

Comment: I believe this is exactly `\againframe` designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1-2>[label=foo]
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<1> foo
  \item<2> bar
   \item<3> baz
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{second}
  Some examples
\end{frame}

\againframe<3>{foo}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it work with several interruptions (like another example between `\item<3>` and an `\item<4>` ? )

Comment: @hl037_ Why don't you try? :)

Comment: @hl037_ Sure... as long as the number of "interruptions" is smaller then 2147483647 you should be save.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never noticed `\againframe`. Very useful.